# Pentest Framework for Webservices?

Tags: web-services, sql-injection, penetration-testing

Is there a pentest framework, especially sql injections, for (java, axis) webservices?
Like a SoapUI for pentester or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, But I Have A List For Testing And Pentesting Webservices :
Tools :

- SOA CLEANER
- WcfStorm-Lite
- Wsdigger
- WsScanner

I Am Use Soa Cleaner And SoapUi For Web Service Pentesing

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best method to pentest a webservice is :

1. Find all apps that can connect to webservice
2. Install apps and sniff every packet
3. See authentication methods or check inputs in `xml` packet
4. Read carefully WSDL,

By the way The SoapUi is A good tool